# Custom GAE/J Datastore viewer

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Are there any custom made `DatastoreViewer` servlet that can read up the datastore?

I've been trying to search the web but coldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Datastore Viewer Plugin](https://github.com/gaelyk/gaelyk-datastore-viewer-plugin) for [Gealyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com). which provides create/edit/query functionality for development server. Create and edit features are extremely handy because the build in editor doesn't provide it.